# I am trying to post multiple file using SFTP connection but not able to post more than 2 files

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I am trying to post multiple file using SFTP connection. I am using below code to connect SFTP server and post file on server.

My program running properly but for only 2 file not more than that, third file on words its generates Authentication error "com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail".

Could you please somebody guide me for that.

```
public boolean putSftp(String input , String fileName) {

    JSch jsch = new JSch();         

    Session session = null;

    try {

      System.out.println("Input : "+input+": File Name :"+fileName+" :-----------Logon on to the Server---------- : "+ datetime);            
      session = jsch.getSession(USER_NAME, FTP_HOSTNAME, 22); 

      session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

      session.setPassword(PASSWORD); 

      session.connect(); 

      Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");

      channel.connect();   

      ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel; 

      sftpChannel.cd(TO_DIRECTORY);

      sftpChannel.put(input+fileName, fileName);

      System.out.println("File sucessfully posted on server....:"+datetime); 

      sftpChannel.exit();

      session.disconnect();

      result = true;

    }catch (JSchException e) {

        System.out.println("Here JSCH...!!! : ");

      e.printStackTrace();

    }catch (SftpException e) { 

        System.out.println("Here SFTP...!!! :");

      e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (Exception e){

        System.out.println("Here Exception...!!!"+e);

    }finally {

      System.out.println("In Side of SFTP Method....."+result);
    }

    return result;
  }
```

Comment: So you are calling 3 times `putSftp` and on the 3rd call it fails ? Try to trace the important things (PASSWORD, etc), maybe they are changing between calls in other part of the code ?

Comment: I'd check if this code is being called by threads and if the sftp server has any simultaneous connection restriction

Comment: I'd expect some problem along the lines @Leo suggested. Check server-side log.